# Why is there a difference in using method ".plot()" between jupyter notebook and pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm following pandas tutorial[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html) with pycharm.

Tutorial describes how to use method '.plot()' with jupyter-notebook as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdhkY.png)

But if I write this code in pycharm, nothing is shown.
if I change code as below, it works same with image

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    air_quality = pd.read_csv("air_quality_no2.csv", index_col=0, 
    parse_dates=True)

    plt.plot(air_quality)
    plt.show()
```

Why is there a difference in using method ".plot()" between jupyter notebook and pycharm?

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is `plt.show()`. Jupyter automatically shows figures without calling `plt.show()`, but otherwise you need to manually call `plt.show()`.

Comment: `air_quality.plot()` uses the [pandas dataframe plotting method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), but that's unrelated to jupyter vs pycharm. You can also use that in pycharm as long as you call `plt.show()`.